# Fill not working with areaRadial() generated shape

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm currently working on a thing which is supposed to look like a lava lamp later. Unfortunately, I'm already failing at the beginning:
I managed to create randomly generated blobs, but I just can't apply a fill. The stroke works just fine.

here is the relevant code which creates the blobs:

```
var ctx = this; // context

this.path = d3.areaRadial()
    .angle(function(d) {return d.theta})
    .radius(function(d) {return d.r})
    .curve(d3.curveCatmullRomClosed.alpha(1));

// create the blob
this.create = function() {
    var anchors = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < ctx.options.anchors; i++) {
        var currTheta = i * (360 / ctx.options.anchors) + rand(ctx.options.spread.theta);
        var currRadians = Math.radians(currTheta);
        var currRadius = ctx.options.radius + rand(ctx.options.spread.r);

        anchors.push({theta: currRadians, r: currRadius});
    }

    var pathData = ctx.path(anchors);
    d3.select(ctx.options.target).append('path')
        .attr('d', pathData)
        .attr('class', 'blob')
        .style('opacity', ctx.options.opacity)
        .style('transform', 'translate(' + ctx.x + 'px, ' + ctx.y + 'px)')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + ctx.x + 'px, ' + ctx.y + 'px)');

    console.log(pathData);
}

function rand(x) // creates a random number between -0.5 * x and 0.5 * x
```

Full code: https://codepen.io/normanwink/pen/BrMVrE

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the expected behaviour, since you're using [radius](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#areaRadial_radius), which is:

> Equivalent to area.y, except the accessor returns the radius: the distance from the origin ⟨0,0⟩.

And for `area.y`:

> If y is specified, **sets y0 to y and y1 to null** and returns this area generator. If y is not specified, returns the current y0 accessor. (emphasis mine)

Therefore, you probably want `outerRadius` here.

```
this.path = d3.areaRadial()
    .angle(function(d) {
        return d.theta
    })
    .outerRadius(function(d) {
        return d.r
    })
    .curve(d3.curveCatmullRomClosed.alpha(1));
```

This is your code with that change only:

```js
(function() {
 "use strict";
 
 // window size
 var windowX = window.innerWidth;
 var windowY = window.innerHeight;
 
 var svgX = windowX;
 var svgY = windowY;
 
 var blobCount = 1;
 
 function init() {
  // console.log(new Blob());
  
  var svg = d3.select('#svg')
   .attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + svgX + ' ' + svgY)
   .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin meet');
    
  for (var i = 0; i < blobCount; i++) {
   var newBlob = new Blob(svgX * 0.5, svgY * 0.5);
  }
 }
 
 function Blob(x, y) {
  var ctx = this; // context
  
  this.options = {
   anchors: 8,
   breathe: 30,
   fill: '#ffffff',
   opacity: 0.5,
   radius: 150,
   spread: {
    theta: 10, // angle
    r: 300 // radius
   },
   target: '#svg',
  };
  
  this.x = x || 0;
  this.y = y || 0;
  
  this.path = d3.areaRadial()
   .angle(function(d) {return d.theta})
   .outerRadius(function(d) {return d.r})
   .curve(d3.curveCatmullRomClosed.alpha(1));
  
  // create the blob
  this.create = function() {
   var anchors = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < ctx.options.anchors; i++) {
    var currTheta = i * (360 / ctx.options.anchors) + rand(ctx.options.spread.theta);
    var currRadians = Math.radians(currTheta);
    var currRadius = ctx.options.radius + rand(ctx.options.spread.r);
    
    anchors.push({theta: currRadians, r: currRadius});
   }
   
   var pathData = ctx.path(anchors);
   d3.select(ctx.options.target).append('path')
    .attr('d', pathData)
    .attr('class', 'blob')
    .style('opacity', ctx.options.opacity)
    .style('transform', 'translate(' + ctx.x + 'px, ' + ctx.y + 'px)')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + ctx.x + 'px, ' + ctx.y + 'px)');
    
  }
  
  // update position and anchor movement
  this.update = function() {
   
  }
  
  // apply changes
  this.render = function() {
   
  }
  
  this.create();
 }
 
 function rand(i) {
  return (Math.random()-0.5) * (i || 1);
 }
 
 Math.radians = function(degrees) {
  return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
 };
 
 // init when ready
 init();

})();
```

```css
#svg {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 1;
}

.blob {
 fill: blue; /* why is this not working? */
 stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg"></svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your `pathData` , because if you replace your `.attr('d', pathData)` with  `.attr('d', 'M37,17v15H14V17z M50,0H0v50h50z')` which is a valid path, your fill is working properly.

I will continue searching the issue, just want to give you a hint, maybe you will find the issue faster then me. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also found out that it's the path, but I had no idea how to debug that since it's auto-generated from D3. Well, Gerardo found the answer.